# Why is std::none_of faster than a hand rolled loop?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I benchmarked the performance of `std::none_of` against a three different manual implementations using i) a `for` loop, ii) a range-based `for` loop and iii) iterators. To my surprise, I found that while all three manual implementations take roughly the same time, `std::none_of` is significantly faster. My question is - why is this the case?

I used the Google benchmark library and compiled with `-std=c++14 -O3`. When running the test, I restricted the affinity of the process to a single processor. I get the following result using GCC 6.2:

```
Benchmark                  Time           CPU Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------
benchmarkSTL           28813 ns      28780 ns      24283
benchmarkManual        46203 ns      46191 ns      15063
benchmarkRange         48368 ns      48243 ns      16245
benchmarkIterator      44732 ns      44710 ns      15698
```

On Clang 3.9, `std::none_of` is also faster than the manual `for` loop though the speed difference is smaller. Here is the test code (only including the manual for loop for brevity):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <functional>
#include <random>

const size_t N = 100000;
const unsigned value = 31415926;

template<size_t N>
std::array<unsigned, N> generateData() {
    std::mt19937 randomEngine(0);
    std::array<unsigned, N> data;
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), randomEngine);
    return data;
}

void benchmarkSTL(benchmark::State & state) {
    auto data = generateData<N>();
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        bool result = std::none_of(
            data.begin(),
            data.end(),
            std::bind(std::equal_to<unsigned>(), std::placeholders::_1, value));
        assert(result);
    }
}

void benchmarkManual(benchmark::State & state) {
    auto data = generateData<N>();
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        bool result = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (data[i] == value) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        assert(result);
    }
}

BENCHMARK(benchmarkSTL);
BENCHMARK(benchmarkManual);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Note that generating the data using a random number generator is irrelevant. I get the same result when just setting the `i`-th element to `i` and checking if the value `N + 1` is contained.

Comment: Why not compare a) the implementation, and b) the generated code?

Comment: I don't know why in your case but because the library is provided by the compiler implementation they are able to use platform specific tricks (eg branch prediction hints?) to provide Standard C++ behavior. So this result (if valid) wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: It seems to be related to the fact that you're using unsigned integers: Compilers can assume that for signed integers there never is an overflow (as it is undefined behaviour according to the standard) and use this fact to aggressively optimize. Apparently `std::none_of` has a specialization for unsigned integers that you are not getting in your handwritten functions. If you swich to `long` instead of `size_t` and `unsigned` the manual version is actually faster.

Comment: @Corristo: I changed `size_t` and `unsigned` to `long` as you suggested. This did not change the results for the STL case but increased the speed of my manual test cases to ~36 mikros.

Comment: @LocalVolatility Hmm, this seems to be highly dependent on the compiler as well... Clang++ 4.0: benchmarkManual - 30µs, benchmarkSTL - 35µs, g++ 6.1: benchmarkManual - 38µs, benchmarkSTL - 29µs.

Comment: Btw, my benchmarks above where with the change to signed integers, with the original version I get Clang++ 4.0: benchmarkManual - 37µs, benchmarkSTL - 27µs; g++ 6.1: benchmarkManual - 45µs, benchmarkSTL - 31µs. At least here STL is consistently faster across both compilers. (In both cases compiled with `-std=c++1z` and `-O3`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more investigation, I will try to answer my own question. As suggested by Kerrek SB, I looked at the generated assembly code. The bottom line seems to be that GCC 6.2 does a much better job at unrolling the loop implicit in `std::none_of` compared to the other three versions.

**GCC 6.2:**

- `std::none_of` is unrolled 4 times -> ~30µs
- manual `for`, range `for` and iterator are not being unrolled at all -> ~45µs

As suggested by Corristo, the result is compiler dependend - which makes perfect sense. Clang 3.9 unrolls all but the range `for` loop, though to varying degrees.

**Clang 3.9**

- `std::none_of' is unrolled 8 times -> ~30µs
- manual `for` is unrolled 5 times -> ~35µs
- range `for` is not being unrolled at all -> ~60µs
- iterator is unrolled 8 times -> ~28µs

*All code was compiled with `-std=c++14 -O3`.*

Comment: I ended up filing the inconsistent unrolling of Clang as a bug: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30628.